# 1 pixel difference between IE11 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Here is the sample code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> IE11 </title>
  <style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    table{
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    td{
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <table width="400px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="400px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col1
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col2
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col3
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table width="400px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col1
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:200px">
                        col2 col3
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px">
                        col4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

In IE10 and IE11, there is an 1 pixel shift in the merged columns:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSNMK.png

But when I run it in IE6-9 or in IE11 with Edge=5, it renders perfectly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhKE.png

It is barely noticeable, but when the elements of td of main table is large, it's very irritating. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there no DOCTYPE in the original source either?

Comment: And I don't think there's something like edge=5.

Comment: I have tried all types of !DOCTYPE, but nothing happens!

Comment: That's odd, because if I add a DOCTYPE and load it in IE8, it behaves the same way as IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how width is calculated including borders or not.

You can solve this using box-sizing css property:

```
td{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough reputation to vote up ;). I'll do it as soon as possible ;)

Comment: To accept an answer, you just have to click on the check mark ✓, not to vote up. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is 1) add a proper DOCTYPE declaration on top, 2) not use compatibility mode, and 3) allow for the widths of the borders in between the table cells. So that would be 99px for the narrow table cells and 199px for the wide one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> IE11 </title>
  <style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    table{
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    td{
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col1
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col2
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col3
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col1
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:199px">
                        col2 col3
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:99px">
                        col4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

This will behave the same, not just in all IE versions, but in all other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with using a single table?

HTML

```
<table width="400px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">col1</td>
        <td style="width:100px">col2</td>
        <td style="width:100px">col3</td>
        <td style="width:100px">col4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px">col1</td>
        <td colspan="2" style="width:200px">col2 col3</td>
        <td style="width:100px">col4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td {
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding: 0 0 0 0;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wkf6g0pa/)

Comment: I think "why can't you use a single table" should be a comment, not an answer.